# Find a script in head with jquery based on it's data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my content editor you can change custom webfonts on the fly. If you change a font, it deletes all scripts and styles using the data-attribute as an identifier and the new ones then get appended after an ajax call. Now after some testing i realised it work's very well with  css files but it ignores the < script >'s. Any ideas? Here is my Script:

```
$('head').find('[data-fontset-id=ce-fontset]').each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

For example this is how the head section looks like:

```
<link data-fonset-id="ce-fontset" rel="stylesheet" href="..........">
<script data-fonset-id="ce-fontset" type="text/javascript" src="//use.typekit.net/xxxxx.js"></script>
<script data-fonset-id="ce-fontset" type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
```

In this example, the css file gets removed but the javascript files didnt, any ideas why they are being ignored?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Michael

Comment: Removing the JavaScript files is not going to do anything.

Comment: By the time you remove the `script` tag the content of the script has already been downloaded and executed. This approach will not solve your problem.

Comment: Ok then its time for some brainstorming for another solution! Thanks!